# Firebase asynchronous query

Tags: ios, swift, firebase

I've just started my journey with Firebase and I am pretty new when it comes to Swift.

I am trying to query a data from the Firebase server

```
func getResults() -> [String] {
    let queryRef = ref.childByAppendingPath("objects")
    var results = [String]()
    queryRef.queryOrderedByChild("name").observeEventType(.ChildAdded, withBlock: { (snapshot) in
        if let number = snapshot.value["number"] as? String {
            results.append(number)
        }
    })
    return results
}
```

I know the querying works asynchronously, but is there a way to actually tell the function to wait for the results and then return them?

EDIT:

Completed function:

```
func getResults(completion: ((objects: [String] -> Void)) {
    let queryRef = ref.childByAppendingPath("objects")
    var results = [String]()
    queryRef.queryOrderedByChild("name").observeEventType(.ChildAdded, withBlock: { (snapshot) in
        if let number = snapshot.value["number"] as? String {
            results.append(number)
        }
        if results.count == Int(snapshot.childrenCount) {
        completion(objects: results)
        }
    })
}
```

Comment: I know about them, but how to actually wait for the Firebase to go through all the objects that I want to query and then run the completion handler?

Comment: Do not use Firebase as a function. Functions are (generally) synchronous. Firebase is asynchronous and your code will execute a lot faster than firebase can return the results, so your return will run before there's any data. If you are wanting to populate a tableView, one solution is to observe the node by .Value, iterate over those results to populate your array. When that iteration has completed, update the tableView. ALL of that is done within the block/closure. However, .Value may return a LOT of results so there are other options depending on how much data there is

Comment: But how to know that the iteration is completed?
Am I doing it right? Edit posting in a minute.

Comment: You don't wait, you should never never never never ever wait. Instead you use a closure, as already mentioned. Beginners want to force asynchronous programming into sequential programming as thats what they're familiar with and its easier to understand, but you can't force a square peg into a round hole. You have to change your code and overall design and your mindset when dealing with asynchronicity.

Comment: You probably will not want to use childAdded as it loads one node at a time. While technically you could do it, your tableView.reload data would fire after each node is loaded, which would be a lot of refreshes. There's a cool process to do an initial load and then monitor other events thereafter in the [FireChat](https://github.com/firebase/firechat-ios) example on the firebase website. Search the project for initialLoad and the code is around that. I gave you a quickie example using .Value in my answer.

Comment: There is no tableView in the project (there will be soon), but all I want to do is get the access to the database where addresses of object are stored, translate them using geocoding and get the coordinates. Anyway - thanks, your advices were really helpful!

Comment: I was using tableView as an example, but it really applies to whatever you are doing with your results array.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution to populate an array that will be used as a tableView datasource, or a series of coordinates or to help track your wife's collection of shoes.

```
var emailArray = [String]()

users.observeSingleEventOfType(.Value, withBlock: { snapshot in

    for child in snapshot.children {
         let email = child.value.objectForKey("email")
         emailArray.append(email!)
    }
    self.tableView.reloadData
})
```

Firebase would look like

```
users
  uid_0
    email: "dude@thing.com"
  uid_1
    email: "person@thing.com"
```

You would probably define the emailArray as a class level variable so your tableView can use it as it's datasource - if that's the case, use self.emailArray.append...

Also, this example is a one-shot load of the usersNode. It will not continue to observe the node for changes.